# Generate random numbers between 0.001359 and 1

Tags: excel, random, vba

I was doing a problem and using the function rnd() but the random values <0.001359 were making other values not acceptable.

How to generate random numbers beginning at 0.001359 until 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a random number greater than or equal to 0.001359 and less than 1.

```
0.001359 + Rnd() * 0.998641
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate numbers between 1359 and 1000000, and then divide the result by 1000000.

The command for generating the random numbers will be

```
Int ((1000000 - 1359 + 1) * Rnd + 1359)
```

For more information look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php).

Comment: Thanks :) i had already tried one similar to this but the problem is that it gives numbers with just 6 or less decimals, and i wanted with more decimals

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula (Excel 2013):

```
=(RANDBETWEEN(1359,1000000)) / 1000000
```

Since it only returns whole numbers, just slide the decimal as needed and then divide the result to get back to you decimal.

To do that in VBA, you can use this:

```
randomnumber = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1359, 1000000) / 1000000
```

Comment: Thanks i had already tried this but the problem is that it gives numbers with just 6 or less decimals, and i wanted with more decimals