Generate Random Decimal Numbers with fixed values in excel VBA
Below VBA code is working perfectly for Whole Numbers. But can't generate decimal random numbers.
Private Sub RandGen()

    Dim total As Double
    Dim numCells As Integer
    Dim minValue As Double
    Dim maxValue As Double
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Define parameters
    total = 30
    numCells = 20 'Row Numbers
    minValue = 1.5
    maxValue = 2.2

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A" & numCells + 2)

    rng.ClearContents

    ' Generate and distribute random numbers
    Randomize ' Initialize the random number generator
    For i = 1 To numCells - 1
        Set Cell = rng.Cells(i, 1)
        Cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(minValue, maxValue)
        total = total - Cell.Value
    Next i
    ' The last cell gets the remaining value to ensure the sum is 30
    rng.Cells(numCells, 1).Value = total
End Sub

Please help.

Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159161/generate-random-numbers-between-0-001359-and-1

Use: Cell.Value = minValue + Rnd * (maxValue - minValue) but the last value will probably be negative, because 20 * minValue = 30. Is this the expected result?

Mr. @MGonet, Perfect Solution. Thank You Very Much.

Mr. @black-cat, Thanks for your suggest. My question is VBA Coding based, and your suggestion is Excel Formula based.

Excel formulas simply can adapt in vba. Other hand the algorithm can be applied. The word similar  direct to this.
